# Windows batch file to replace line feeds

Tags: batch-file

Looking to remove the incorrect carriage returns "CRLF" in a file but retain the correct ones. I think I have some logic that will work but can't quite nail the script.

Where ^p represents a “carriage return”

Replace Yes^p with yestemp
Replace No^p with notemp
Replace Inactive^p with inactivetemp
Replace ^p with “” (ie null)
Replace Yestemp with Yes^p
Replace notempwith No^p
Replace inactivetemp with Inactive^p

Comment: Do you *really* need this for DOS? Not Windows by any chance?

Comment: I have the same question as Joey. In addition, your language is inconsistent, Your title talks about line feed (byte code 10, hex 0x0A), You refer to `^p` as representing "carriage return" (byte code 13, hex 0x0D). And your first sentence talks about carriage returns as "CRLF", which is a common shorthand for the combination of carriage return and line feed, used by Windows (and DOS) as line terminators. So, what exactly are you really trying to do?

Comment: Also, do you really want to preserve `^p` (whatever that is supposed to represent) after the words Yes, No, and Inactive, and remove the rest? Or are those words standins for something else?

Comment: Thanks. 

Let me start again and be more clear. 

The txt file contains both LF and CRLF values.
The strings I want to retain are YesLF and NoLF.
I'd like to remove all other LF and CRLF strings 

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do this with pure native batch, but it would be very painful, and likely very slow.

This is trivial using [JREPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe files required. Full documentation is built into the utility, accessed via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged output.

The solutions below are based on the specs from your comment:

> BlockquoteThe txt file contains both LF and CRLF values. The strings I want to retain are YesLF and NoLF. I'd like to remove all other LF and CRLF strings

Here is a solution using the `/T` option

```
jrepl "(Yes|No)\n:\r?\n" "$&:" /t ":" /m /f "yourFile.txt" /o -
```

And here is a solution using the `/J` option with a bit of user supplied JScript

```
jrepl "((Yes|No)(?=\n))?\r?\n" "$1?$0:''" /j /m /f "yourFile.txt" /o -
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidAnton - Thanks are nice, but the proper way to do that on this site is to accept an answer that fully answers your question by clicking on the check-mark near the upper left corner. That awards the answer poster 15 rep points, and you, the questioner, get 2 rep points for taking the time to accept an answer. Only one question may be accepted. Once you reach 15 rep points, then you gain the ability to up vote any answer you find useful, which awards 10 points to the answer poster. You can up vote as many answers as you want, even answers to other people's questions.